# TFS Web Calling an external REST Service throws 401 error

Tags: rest, tfs, unauthorized

When creating a web hook within TFS (to access an external rest service url), I get a 401 error when testing (within the TFS application). I think call is not hitting API at all.

Below is the response I can see

```
Status Code: 401
Reason Phrase: Unauthorized
HTTP Version: 1.1
Headers:
{
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
  WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
  WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE8
  Date: Fri, 30 Mar 2018 21:05:26 GMT
  Content-Length: 1293
  Content-Type: text/html
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think the error is quite obvious. You are getting authentication from the external service and you are using windows authentication. Check permissions on the target service.

Comment: my user id has access to this API (web api)

Answer (score 1):

The error ID 401 usually related to the authorization.

You could first use postman to double check user ID access to the API.

Also use week hook to access some other rest service url such as the example in [Web Hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=vsts). This will narrow down if the issue related to  rest service url.

Besides try to use  **Basic Authentication**, you can use alternate account instead.  How to please take a look at:[Protecting a VSTS Web Hook with Basic Authentication](http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/protecting-a-vsts-web-hook-with-basic-authentication)